# How do I add markup to the "JNews" WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, markup, googlebot

I am receiving a critical error from Google Search stating, missing field "contentUrl"

I have looked up a few different ways to fix, but none have been effective. Obviously, I am a plug-n-play rookie and could use some guidance.

Thanks in advance!

I have attempted to update my robot.txt file to allow Googlebot through, no change.

I have tried to update the header.pfp file in WordpPress Theme Editor to place amended  file, no change.

Tried to update header.pfp with  code from Google Search docs, no change.

Tried to update robots.txt file to allow Googlebot, no change.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.